# functions.php doesn't load all custom theme assets

Tags: php, theme-development, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

I'm writing a simple wordpress theme. I've added this function inside the `functions.php` file and I've noticed that only style.css is loaded. Is there something wrong that will cause that the other scripts aren't loaded?

```php
function load_theme_assets()
{
    //wp_register_style( $handle:string, $src:string|false, $deps:array, $ver:string|boolean|null, $media:string )
    wp_register_style(
        'main',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        false
    );
    wp_enqueue_style('main');

    //wp_register_script( $handle:string, $src:string|false, $deps:array, $ver:string|boolean|null, $in_footer:boolean )
    wp_register_script(
        'main',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/index.js',
        [],
        false,
    );
    wp_enqueue_script('main');

    wp_register_style(
        'bootstrap',
        'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
        false
    );
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_theme_assets');

?>
```

Comment: Is the script not loading or is it not _working_? It’s an important difference. Do you see the script tags in the HTML or not.

Comment: do you see failed loading errors on the frontend? How are you testing that the scripts are failing to load? Note that loading Bootstrap from a CDN is not more performant unless you're using a 10 year old browser and can actually be much slower ( modern browsers keep separate caches for each pages domain so there's no shared cache for CDNs ), and there are regulatory consequences too, this may not be GDPR compatible if we go by recent Google Fonts rulings

Comment: no, the script will not load, no error is logged in console. This is what is strange. In my index.php I've included the `get_header()` and `get_footer()` functions and only the style.css is loaded

Comment: But have you used `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` inside of the header and footer?

Comment: @ICTDEV, how did you confirm this - "*the script will not load*" - are you sure the raw/server-generated HTML source does not contain a script tag for your script? Are you sure the script is at `get_template_directory_uri() . '/index.js'` (i.e. the path is correct and that it exists)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your mistake is using `main` as handle keyword for both script and style, handle must be unique.
You don't have to use `wp_register_script` (and style) enqueue function does this automatically. You typically use `wp_register_script`(style) only if you are not sure if script/style will be needed later, if it is enqueued conditionally, but you want to avoid having several versions of the same script/style loaded. You should check browsers console, you might as well specified incorrect path to those scripts. You can also use newer `get_theme_file_uri()` function to find path for scripts/styles which has some advantages (see manual).

Comment: I've read on a post that the `wp_register_style` `wp_register_script` functions can be used in combination with the `wp_enqueue_script` `wp_enqueue_style` functions. Probably my mistake is to use the same id for both scripts, I will test by changing the handle. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: They CAN be used, but I explained why this is often not necessary